# concat string in array ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a problem to solve. This problem is basically concat one value inside my array. But the problem is my array won't accept a value I will concat inside the array. Below is my code.

```
interface SpecialtiesListProps {
  specialtyId: number;
  rqe: string;
}

const [id, setId] = useState<SpecialtiesListProps[]>([]);
const [uf, setUf] = useState('');

const handleChange = (value: string, SpecialtyId: number) => {
    const newIdFilter = id.find((item) => item.specialtyId === SpecialtyId);
    if (!newIdFilter) {
      setId([...id, {specialtyId: SpecialtyId, rqe: value}]);
    } else {
      setId(
        id.map((item) => {
          if (item.specialtyId === SpecialtyId) {
            return {specialtyId: Number(item.specialtyId), rqe: value};
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        }),
      );
    }   
      const newId = id.concat({uf})
      setId(newId) 
  };
```

The error that appears for me is this:

> ```
> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(...items:
> ConcatArray<SpecialtiesListProps>[]): SpecialtiesListProps[]', gave
> the following error.
>     Argument of type '{ uf: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<SpecialtiesListProps>'.
>       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uf' does not exist in type 'ConcatArray<SpecialtiesListProps>'.   Overload 2 of
> 2, '(...items: (SpecialtiesListProps |
> ConcatArray<SpecialtiesListProps>)[]): SpecialtiesListProps[]', gave
> the following error.
>     Argument of type '{ uf: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SpecialtiesListProps | ConcatArray<SpecialtiesListProps>'.
>       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uf' does not exist in type 'SpecialtiesListProps |
> ConcatArray<SpecialtiesListProps>'.ts(2769)
> ```

I don`t know how to solve that and I spent many hours trying to solve that.

Below is a print of error to help:

[image: here is a print of error]

Comment: why are you calling `setId` twice inside the else statement ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé i set this because i need change the id to this new with the concatenated string

Comment: @caTS thanks for your answear, when this cause this error ** No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<SpecialtiesListProps>[]): SpecialtiesListProps[]', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SpecialtiesListProps'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: (SpecialtiesListProps | ConcatArray<SpecialtiesListProps>)[]): SpecialtiesListProps[]', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SpecialtiesListProps'.** you can help me whit this?

Answer (score 1):

`setId` has type `{specialtyId: number; rqe: string;}` or in other words, type `SpecialitiesListProps`. On the other hand, `uf` has type `string`. `string` and `SpecialitiesListProps` aren't the same type, so TypeScript is throwing an error, because the `id` will not be type `SpecialitiesListProps` anymore if a type string is added to the array. You must either make `uf` type `SpecialitiesListProps`, or transform the `uf` string into a `SpecialitiesListProps` type. In addition, concat merges two arrays, so you need to pass in `[{specialityId: number, rqe: string}]` not an object like `{string}`

```
import { useState } from "react";
interface SpecialtiesListProps {
  specialtyId: number;
  rqe: string;
}

const [id, setId] = useState<SpecialtiesListProps[]>([]);
const [uf, setUf] = useState("");

const handleChange = (value: string, SpecialtyId: number) => {
  const newIdFilter = id.find((item) => item.specialtyId === SpecialtyId);
  if (!newIdFilter) {
    setId([...id, { specialtyId: SpecialtyId, rqe: value }]);
  } else {
    setId(
      id.map((item) => {
        if (item.specialtyId === SpecialtyId) {
          return { specialtyId: Number(item.specialtyId), rqe: value };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })
    );
  }
  //this is an example change. modify this line for your use case
  const newId = id.concat([{ specialityId: 10, rqe: uf }]);
  setId(newId);
};
```